# Counting Problems with n-Bit Strings

Tags: combinatorics

I'm a little confused with problems regarding n-bit strings- for instance if we are considering the number of n-bit strings of size n with a 1001 pattern, why is it alright to consider only adding things onto **one** side when generating recurrence relations? Is this an obvious fact, or is it something that generally confuses people? I think I understand that if we consider adding to one side, adding to the other side *should* be handled when we talk about the number of n-1 bit strings, but it still feels like a leap of faith for me.

For instance, the number of n bit strings with 1001 would be something like the number of n-1 bit strings with 1001 patterns, times 2 by adding a 1 or 0 on the end, plus some other things, but that already confuses me. Initially, I feel as if adding on a 1 or a 0 should be consider for *both* sides, so I feel like I would want to multiply by 4. Is there a better way of understanding this?

Comment: As long as your procedure generates each desired string once and only once, it will give a correct recurrence. In the usual examples, a complete analysis can be made by appending only, or alternately by prepending only.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about converse. We should check that both directions work out: going from smaller strings to larger strings, and from larger string to smaller strings.  It sometimes goes without mention from these proofs.

The simplest non-trivial case is $n$-bit strings without $11$ (so let's use this as an example).  Other cases are similar in flavor, but the method of counting might change.

- *One direction*: Given an $n$-bit binary string without $11$:

  - If it ends with $1$, then it ends in $01$, so we can delete the last two bits to obtain a *unique* $(n-2)$-bit binary string without $11$.
  - If it ends with $0$, then we can delete the last bit to obtain a *unique* $(n-1)$-bit binary string without $11$.
- *The other direction*:

  - Given a $(n-2)$-bit binary string without $11$, we can append $01$ to the end to get a *unique* $n$-bit binary string without $11$.
  - Given a $(n-1)$-bit binary string without $11$, we can append $0$ to the end to get a *unique* $n$-bit binary string without $11$.

This gives a bijection between the $n$-bit strings without $11$ and the $(n-1)$-bit strings without $11$ $\bigcup$ the $(n-2)$-bit strings without $11$.  This is illustrated below:

[image: Bijection]

We could proceed similarly and add bits at either end.  It doesn't make the proof any easier though.  If we did that in the above case:

- Every $n$-bit string without $11$ would be paired up with exactly $2$ smaller strings without $11$ (either $(n-1)$-bit or $(n-2)$-bit).
- Every $(n-1)$-bit and $(n-2)$-bit string without $11$ would be paired up with exactly $2$ $n$-bit strings.

So the number of edges in the figure would double, but the result would still hold:  The number of edges going out of the left is $2$ times the number of $(n-1)$-bit strings without $11$ plus the number of $(n-2)$-bit strings without $11$.  This is equal to the number of edges going into the right, which is $2$ times the nmber of $n$-bit strings without $11$.  So the $2$'s cancel out and we get the same recurrence.